# Obtaining record from Solr using single Key

Tags: solr

I am using solr and looked over the documentations but couldn't find a way to get a single record from Solr by using a key?

If I know the key value of the record what is the query I need to pass to Solr to obtain this record?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by key, but guessing from context, you mean a field defined by your schema, if this is the case, you could issue the following:

```
// Assumes Id is a schema field

// If via solr admin
q=Id:1

// Properly escaped
q=Id%3A1
```

Comment: Actually it's coming in as uid in the response so q=uid:xxx works. Thank you for your help.